# Between clause - do I have to reorder the parameters?

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I have what seems like a very silly question to me. I have a query that looks something like:

```
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE valueCol BETWEEN :x and :y;
```

This works great when `:x <= :y` BUT, when `:x > :y` it doesn't return the rows I want! For this case I have to manually reverse the variables to get it to work correctly.

Is there a way to write a between clause where the order of the variables doesn't matter?

PS> I included SQL since I am pretty sure this is just a general sql issue.

Comment: The [fine manual published online by Oracle which is freely available to anyone for the cost of a Google search](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions011.htm#SQLRF52147) indicates that x must in fact by <= y.

Comment: As to your PS: It is good you tagged this as "sql" - no matter if this is a general SQL issue or not. Your question relates to Oracle SQL (rather than partitioning strategies in Oracle, optimal server settings or whatever), so tagging this "oracle"  plus "sql" is perfect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes that's easy:

```
SELECT id 
FROM myTable 
WHERE valueCol BETWEEN LEAST(:x,:y) and GREATEST(:x,:y);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do the check yourself and swap the values, or, you could do something like this and let Oracle figure it out:

```
BETWEEN LEAST(:x,:y) AND GREATEST(:x,:y)
```

Comment: Sorry for the follow up - I have to wonder: is there any performance ramification for having Oracle do this work?

Comment: The simple answer is - yes and no. Yes, it doubtless consumes a few CPU cycles to execute LEAST and GREATEST but no, you won't notice it. Share and enjoy.

Comment: @drew_w: There's a tiny bit of extra work to do the actual comparison.  The bigger issue is whether this would influence the optimizer to choose not to make use of an index range scan operation to satisfy the predicate on `valueCol`. (I know that Oracle can do some "bind variable peeking" to get estimates of cardinality, when it develops an exeuction plan. (Ideally, Oracle would evaluate the LEAST and GREATEST expressions, and use the result in developing an execution plan, so there wouldn't make any difference. But I don't know if does or not.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a case:

```
between case when :x <= :y then :x else :y end 
and case when :x <= :y then :y else :x end
```